# How to get Member count from each group along with group details?

Tags: mysql, database

I have following MySQL Tables

```
users      :- user_id (PK)
groups     :- group_id (PK)
user_group :- user_group_id (PK),user_id(F Key),group_id(F Key)
```

I want to know how many groups user has joined along with member count from each group. for example

```
user1 :- group1,group2
user2 :- group2,group3
user3 :- group1,group3
```

now I want result like this

```
user1:1(user_id)  group1:1(group_id) 2(member count)
user1:1(user_id)  group2:2(group_id) 2(member count)
user2:2(user_id)  group2:2(group_id) 2(member count)
user2:2(user_id)  group3:3(group_id) 2(member count)
user3:3(user_id)  group3:3(group_id) 2(member count)
user3:3(user_id)  group2:2(group_id) 2(member count)
```

Is it possible using single query or else what's better way?

Comment: just add what i have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible it is also a quite horrible query it'll be something like this would seriously recommend doing it differently though :(

```
SELECT users.user_id,groups.group_id,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_group WHERE user_group.group_id=groups.group_id) FROM groups INNER JOIN user_group ON groups.group_id=user_group.group_id INNER JOIN users ON user_group.user_id=users.user_id ORDER BY users.user_id,groups.group_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.user_id, A.group_id, B.count FROM user_group A 
LEFT JOIN (
   select group_id, count(*) as count FROM user_group GROUP BY group_id) B 
ON A.group_id = B.group_id
```

Comment: thanks @szapio but it's taking more time than what Dave mention

Comment: @kamlesh.bar no problem i tried to write as simple query as i could, maybe because of LEFT JOIN its slow, try with INNER JOIN, maybe it will be faster

Comment: @szapio That would leave out  the users that hadn't joined any groups, wouldn't it?